# making a JPanel into a JOptionPane.OK_OPTION

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jpanel, joptionpane

currently i have a class which extends JPanel and basically shows some information about an object passed into its constructor. There are various labels and Image icons on the screen and has a BorderLayout set.

This panel is triggered when the user left clicks on an ImageIcon from the main GUI and shows up on the screen.

i was wondering, how (if there is a way) i could implement the JOptionPane.OK_OPTION onto the whole Panel so that i dont have to close the panel using Event handling, as the screen is simply to show information and when the user has finished, they press okay and the panel should close off.

thanks
Jordan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply pass the object of that `JPanel` within the `JOptionPane`. For example:

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.add(new JButton("Click"));
 panel.add(new JTextField(20));
 panel.add(new JLabel("Label"));
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,panel,"Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Above code will put the `JPanel` on `JOptionPane` message dialog. When you click `OK` the panel closes Off.

Comment: aah i didn't think i would be that simple, i tried variations of this and looked at the API's but couldn't work it out :). thank you :)

Comment: My pleasure. And dont forget to mark the answer as `accepted` if it solved your problem . Look here to know how to accept an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work