# How to make a JFrame dialog like a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() waiting for press a button in Java?

Tags: java, dialog, jframe, joptionpane, always-on-top

I'm not trying to make just a dialog.
I have a JFrame object, and I need it shows first when running other class, but I need that when JFrame object executes, It makes to wait/pause/stop to the main class, something like JOptionPane dialogs. I don't want the other class executes behind the JFrame object, I want it waits to make something (like press a button) in JFrame Object.

Is there a property for that?

How can I do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Google "java action listener".

Comment: No precisely. Only an "action listener" doesn't solve my problem of have the main class waiting the answer in another JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier way to make what I wanted.
To explain, I only created a JPanel with the same design of the JFrame object that I had.
JOptionPane can show custom JPanel objects.
[making a JPanel into a JOptionPane.OK_OPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267562/making-a-jpanel-into-a-joptionpane-ok-option)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Modal (J)Dialog. If you check the Javadocs, you'll see the method setModal.

But the far easier way to do this (IMO) is to create a custom JPanel and show it with JOptionPane using the same showXXXDialog methods you've been using.

Comment: Thanks. But I found an easier way to make what I want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267562/making-a-jpanel-into-a-joptionpane-ok-option