# Boolean Arrays and displaying in JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, joptionpane

I am quite new to Java and am still learning. I have a 4x4 boolean array which are all false and I need to display this in a mannerism such as this 
[image: As you can see it has a 4x4 array, the sectors are green when false and will turn red when true]

along with that I need two JOptionPane Options which one quits the program while the other continues the code.

I have defined my boolean 4x4 array as

```
boolean[][] seating = new boolean[4][4];
```

and attempted a few different things to show this in such a format as above, the seating chart needs to be green when the boolean is false and red when the boolean is true.

Comment: "*...and attempted a few different things to show this in such a format as above...*" -- What have you attempted?  What problem(s) are you having with those attempts?

Comment: went through quite a few different stack overflow questions trying to figure out how to correctly display an array in a joptionpane everything I found seemed to return some strange strings, nor have I found a way to display it in such a graphical mannerism.

Comment: You can use basic HTML in the text label of your JOptionPane to render your array. Or you can use a JPanel as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267562/making-a-jpanel-into-a-joptionpane-ok-option